# Creating a key pair using a deterministic composite seed consisting of human generated passphrase and randomly generated bytes

Tags: cryptography

One of the problems with seed phrases typically used for blockchain wallets is that there is no secondary protection if the seed phrases are stolen. Users tend to screenshot the seed phrases and it is a single point of failure (of being stolen). If a human generated passphrase is added to the seed, it adds one more layer of protection (that they can keep in their mind or write down offline)

Appreciate any help on this.

Step 1) Create a list of human readable words (256 in total, each corresponding to a specific byte value). This is a constant.

```
var MNEMONICS [255]string = [255]string{"ability", "able", "bundle", "cactus", "circle",........,"zero", "zone", "zoo"}
```

Step 2) Generate a random 16 byte array. Each byte in this array corresponds to one of the words from step 1.

```
var part1 byte[16] = RandomBytes(16) //assume random generator is strong
```

Step 3) Ask the user to provide a 16 char password.

```
var part2 byte[16] = ReadUserProvidedPassphrase()
```

Step 4) Concatenate both

```
var seed byte[32] = contact(part1,part2)
```

Step 5) Use above seed as input to ChaCha20, with a constant nonce; (to deterministically generate keypair)

```
var nonce byte[12] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11}

randomGenerator = ChaCha20.initialize(seed, nonce)
```

Step 6) Generate KeyPair using above random

```
kp = KeyGen(randomGenerator)
```

When imports the seed phrase, they also need to provide the passphrase, to get the same KeyPair they used originally, just the seed phrases alone won't be enough.

Questions

Any problems in general with this approach (such as from a brute force attack)?

In step 4,5, is it necessary to pass the human generated input to a KDF?

In step 5, is it ok to have a constant nonce for the application?